# Tensorflow: How to pass a state and an input to LSTMCell?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to write my own recurrent network using LSTM Cells and I'm having trouble passing the state to LSTMCell. In my FeedBack class (based on [tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#advanced_autoregressive_model)) there are following lines to initialize final layers of a model:

```py
class FeedBack(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, units, in_steps, out_steps, graph):
      ...
      self.lstm_cell = tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(units)  # units = 128 in this example
      # Also wrap the LSTMCell in an RNN to simplify the `warmup` method.
      self.lstm_rnn = tf.keras.layers.RNN(self.lstm_cell, return_state=True)
      self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
```

I've also defined a `warmup` method inside which the first prediction is made like so:

```py
...
# merged.shape = (None, 24, 34)

x, *state = self.lstm_rnn(merged)
# x.shape =(None, 128)
# [x.shape for x in state] = [TensorShape([None, 128]), TensorShape([None, 128])]

prediction = self.dense(x)
```

And finally inside a `call` method predictions I'm trying to predict the values with:

```py
...
# merged.shape = (None, 24, 34)
# state remains untouched
x, state = self.lstm_cell(merged, states=state)

prediction = self.dense(x)
```

But it results with the following error:

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 512 and 128 for '{{node feed_back/lstm_cell/mul}} = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT](feed_back/lstm_cell/Sigmoid_1, feed_back/rnn/while/Identity_5)' with input shapes: [?,6,512], [?,128].
```

Where does [?,6,512] come from? And how can I fix this?

Comment: Hey, can you provide a runnable code that includes that problem? Colab sample would be great, for example.

Comment: Here is the google colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1x3_3ZIlN3TT05mcjbEt72HxI9ChidkVT?usp=sharing